# Google Map Reverse Geocoder - Node.js Node-Geocoder

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-geocoder, reverse-geocoding

I am using node-geocoder for one of my projects. It is working fine but in some cases, it is throwing following error randomly :

```
Error: Status is ZERO_RESULTS.
    at /gps/node_modules/node-geocoder/lib/geocoder/googlegeocoder.js:292:25
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/gps/node_modules/node-geocoder/lib/httpadapter/httpadapter.js:62:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

Initially I thought it is the problem of coordinates which I am passing but unfortunately, it is not. If I am passing same coordinates again, it is giving me correct results.

I am using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-geocoder

Comment: You may experience this result if you run you query too often, which violates the usage guidelines: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Comment: Before I was using free version. I used to get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT. But now I am using premium business plan. Now it is showing ZERO_RESULTS... not OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.

Comment: If you have a Premium plan, you are entitled to technical support from Google. Just file a support case as explained in this document: https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/support#contact-support